# Ruby-FFI (ruby 1.8): Reading UTF-16LE encoded strings

Tags: ruby, ffi, ruby-1.8

I am working with Ruby-FFI on Ruby 1.8 to wrap a library that uses UTF-16LE strings. The library has a C function that returns such a String.

Whether I wrap the function with

```
attach_function [:getVersion, [], :pointer]
```

and call `read_string` on the returned pointer, or whether I wrap it with

```
attach_function [:getVersion, [], :string]
```

What I get back is only the first character, because the second character is null (`\000`) and as a result, FFI stops reading the string there, obviously because it assumes it is dealing with a normal, single-null terminated string.

Is there something I need to do, perhaps in initialization of my Ruby program or FFI or otherwise, to make it know that I expect strings to be UTF-16LE encoded? How else can I get around this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, this is the (inelegant) workaround I have so far. It involves adding a method to FFI::Pointer. It should be safe to call in the context of my library, because all strings are supposed to be UTF-16LE encoded, but otherwise, it may not be good, because it might never encounter a double null and would just carry on reading past the the bounds of the string in memory.

```
module FFI
  class Pointer

    # Read string until we encounter a double-null terminator
    def read_string_dn
      cont_nullcount = 0
      offset = 0
      # Determine the offset in memory of the expected double-null
      until cont_nullcount == 2
        byte = get_bytes(offset,1)
        cont_nullcount += 1 if byte == "\000"
        cont_nullcount = 0 if byte != "\000"
        offset += 1
      end
      # Return string with calculated length (offset) including terminator
      get_bytes(0,offset+1)
    end

  end

end
```

Answer (score 0):

More elegant solution based on the same idea. Does handle the encoding too.

```
module FFI
  class Pointer
    def read_wstring
      offset = 0
      while get_bytes(offset, 2) != "\x00\x00"
        offset += 2
      end
      get_bytes(0, offset).force_encoding('utf-16le').encode('utf-8')
    end
  end
end
```